# Putting out camping/cooking fires

Tags: ps4, metro-last-light, metro-2033-redux

Can cooking fires and camp fires be put out in Metro: Last Light Redux? In one DLC level (Pavel I think) they can be put out, but can it be done in the vanilla story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played the metro series in a while but as far I know, no they cannot. I guessing that it doesn't matter too much though but depending on the environment it could help with stealth. Sorry and hope you enjoy the game!

Comment: Thank you. I had just gone through the Bandits level where there were a lot of barrel fires that I couldn't activate. There were some cooking fires that I could pour the kettle of water on them that was sitting there.